# Pinning ArcMap Table of Contents but not Attribute table window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, table-of-contents

I have pinned by table of contents but I would like to view my attribute table as floating - i.e. I can make it much larger so I can view the data easily.

Comment: Yes. Click on the tab and drag it out. Can also dock both; I use a 2-monitor (have tried 3) setup: Arcmap main window on one and TOC, Attributes, Identity view etc.. on the other.

Comment: No problems. I think if you hold down shift (or was that ctrl) it prevents the window from re-docking making it easier to separate.

Answer (score 2):

The best documentation that I have found on how to pin, dock and stack windows in the ArcMap GUI came in the What's New section of the ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 help on a page called [What's new in ArcMap 10 basics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp0000001r000000.htm) in a section called *New dockable window controls make it easy to arrange and organize your display*:

> With ArcGIS 10, you can arrange the windows in your map display any
>   way you want so you can see more of your map and reduce clutter.
>   Dockable windows, such as the table of contents, the ArcToolbox
>   window, the new Catalog window, and the new Search window, are easier
>   to work with.
>
> A new pin control on every dockable window lets you unpin it to
>   autohide it. An autohidden window is shown as a tab in the display,
>   which you can pause over or click to make the window expand whenever
>   you want to use it. After you expand an autohidden window, it will
>   automatically hide itself again when you click somewhere else, such as
>   choosing a tool from a toolbar, or click on the map display. At any
>   time, you can click the pin control again to dock the window so it
>   remains in place.
>
> To move a docked window to a new location, drag its title bar. When
>   you do this, blue targets appear representing the different locations
>   where the window can be docked. Drop the window onto the target of
>   your choice. Pause over a target to get a preview of where the window
>   will be located if you drop it on that target. If you want the window
>   to float over the display instead of being docked, don't drop it onto
>   one of the blue targets.
>
> In addition to being able to dock a window to the left or right or
>   above or below another docked window, you can also stack windows on
>   top of each other so they appear as tabs. This is a convenient way to
>   work with multiple dockable windows. Simply drag one dockable window
>   over another, and you'll see an extra target appear that enables you
>   to stack them together.
>
> You can double-click the title bar of a window to quickly toggle it
>   between docked and undocked. If you've stacked two or more windows
>   together, you can also double-click the tabs with which they are shown
>   to toggle between their being docked and undocked. This is useful, for
>   example, if you normally work with a particular window docked but want
>   to quickly pop it out to be a larger, floating window.

I strongly recommend reading this help page which has graphics to accompany the quoted text because it makes using the ArcMap GUI extremely intuitive.